# is it possible to create a standard function inside a Controller?

Tags: phalcon

Untill now I create actions inside all of my controllers :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class RestaurantLivraisonController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(){
       ...
    }
}
?>
```

But is it possible to create a function , not an action , within a Controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Simply create a method (functions inside classes are called methods) in it like you would do in any other normal PHP class.

It's possible because the Phalcon's routing mechanism always attempts to match the current URL to an action (i.e. a specific method) in a controller class and execute it.  No matter if it finds one or not, it will not care about any other methods in there.

In other words, a method in a Controller class also is an action if it's a route target (and if it's suffixed with "Action"). You can call your custom methods from within an action.

Answer (score 3):

Also you should set them to be private if they are not gonna be actions imho.